# Google Tag Manager container isn't updating

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm running into a weird issue where my changes in Google Tag Manager aren't being reflected on my website.

For example, I update my Google Analytics tag to fire a "Universal Analytics" tag but my website is still firing the "Classic Google Analytics".

If I preview my container, then everything works as expected but if I view the tags without preview mode, I don't see any of the latest changes.

The tags are definitely coming from GTM as you can see in the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMQkT.jpg (couldn't upload to Stackoverflow)

Has anyone experienced this issue? Could caching be affecting the GTM changes?

Comment: Just to verify, did you publish your changes?

Comment: @EmilianoBarboza I think this is it. I just checked and saw that I only have "user" privileges. The publishing button looks the same but it doesn't actually publish the changes.

Comment: Nice. I had the same problem haha.nice to hear that